# Empty query not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i made an admission form, trying to save the inform to database, it is working and saving all the information into database but empty query is not working.

```
<?php
include 'authentication.php';
include 'includes/dbConnect.php';   

$class = $_POST['class'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$date_of_birth = $_POST['date-of-birth'];
$mark_of_identification = $_POST['mark-of-identification'];
$religion = $_POST['religion'];
$father_name = $_POST['father-name'];
$occupation = $_POST['occupation'];
$army_no = $_POST['army-no'];
$rank = $_POST['rank'];
$regt = $_POST['regt'];
$unit = $_POST['unit'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$guardian = $_POST['guardian'];
$guardian_occupation = $_POST['guardian-occupation'];
$mother = $_POST['mother'];
$mother_occupation = $_POST['mother-occupation'];
$present_adress = $_POST['present-adress'];
$permanent_adress = $_POST['permanent-adress'];
$school = $_POST['school'];
$registration_number = $_POST['registration-no'];
$exam = $_POST['exam'];
$ssc_school = $_POST['ssc-school'];
$ssc_year = $_POST['ssc-year'];
$ssc_total_marks = $_POST['ssc-total-marks'];
$ssc_marks = $_POST['ssc-marks'];
$ssc_grade = $_POST['ssc-grade'];
$ssc_percentage = $_POST['ssc-percentage'];
$ssc_sub = $_POST['ssc-sub'];
$exam2 = $_POST['exam2'];
$ssc_ii_school = $_POST['ssc-ii-school'];
$ssc_year_two = $_POST['ssc-year-two'];
$ssc_ii_total_marks = $_POST['ssc-ii-total-marks'];
$ssc_ii_marks = $_POST['ssc-ii-marks'];
$ssc_ii_grade = $_POST['ssc-ii-grade'];
$ssc_ii_percentage = $_POST['ssc-ii-percentage'];
$ssc_sub2 = $_POST['ssc-sub2'];
$exam3 = $_POST['exam3'];
$o_level_school = $_POST['o-level-school'];
$o_level = $_POST['o-level'];
$o_level_total_marks = $_POST['o-level-total-marks'];
$o_level_marks = $_POST['o-level-marks'];
$o_level_grade = $_POST['o-level-grade'];
$o_level_percentage = $_POST['o-level-percentage'];
$o_level_sub = $_POST['o-level-sub'];
$exam4 = $_POST['exam4'];
$hssc_school = $_POST['hssc-school'];
$hssc_year = $_POST['hssc-year'];
$hssc_total_marks = $_POST['o-level-marks'];
$hssc_marks = $_POST['hssc-marks'];
$hssc_grade = $_POST['hssc-grade'];
$hssc_percentage = $_POST['hssc-percentage'];
$hssc_sub = $_POST['hssc-sub'];
$admission_number = $_POST['admission-number'];
$admission_date = $_POST['admission-date'];
$roll_number = $_POST['roll-number'];
$section = $_POST['section'];

        if ($name == '' || $category == '')
            {
            $myURL = 'error.php?eType=pass';
            header('Location: '.$myURL);
    exit;
        }


        $sql1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `school`.`students` (`S_No`, `Roll_No`, `Name`, `Father_Name`, `Class`, `Section`, `Gender`, `Mark_of_identification`, `Date_of_birth`, `Religion`, `Admission_date`, `name_of_last_school`, `Board_registration_number`, `student_category`) VALUES (NULL, '$roll_number', '$name', '$father_name', '$class', '$section', '$gender', '$mark_of_identification', '$date_of_birth', '$religion', '$admission_date', '$school', '$registration_number', '$category');") or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());

        $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `school`.`parents` (`S_No`, `Roll_no`, `Father_name`, `Father_occupation`, `Army_number`, `Rank`, `Corps`, `Unit`, `Contact_number`, `Guardian_name`, `Guardian_occupation`, `Mother_name`, `Mother_occupation`, `Present_address`, `Permanent_address`) VALUES (NULL, '$roll_number', '$father_name', '$occupation', '$army_no', '$rank', '$regt', '$unit', '$contact', '$guardian', '$guardian_occupation', '$mother', '$mother_occupation', '$present_adress', '$permanent_adress');") or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());


        $sql3 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `school`.`academic` (`S_No`, `Exam`, `School`, `Year`, `Total_marks`, `Marks_obtained`, `Grade`, `Percentage`,`Major_subjects`, `Roll_no`) VALUES (NULL, '$exam', '$ssc_school', '$ssc_year', '$ssc_total_marks','$ssc_marks', '$ssc_grade', '$ssc_percentage', '$ssc_sub', '$roll_number');")
         or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());

        if ($exam2!='');
        $sql4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `school`.`academic` (`S_No`, `Exam`, `School`, `Year`, `Total_marks`, `Marks_obtained`, `Grade`, `Percentage`,`Major_subjects`, `Roll_no`) VALUES (NULL, '$exam2', '$ssc_ii_school', '$ssc_year_two', '$ssc_ii_total_marks','$ssc_ii_marks', '$ssc_ii_grade', '$ssc_ii_percentage', '$ssc_sub2', '$roll_number');")
         or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
        if ($exam3!='');
        $sql5 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `school`.`academic` (`S_No`, `Exam`, `School`, `Year`, `Total_marks`, `Marks_obtained`, `Grade`, `Percentage`,`Major_subjects`, `Roll_no`) VALUES (NULL, '$exam3', '$o_level_school', '$o_level', '$o_level_total_marks','$o_level_marks', '$o_level_grade', '$o_level_percentage', '$o_level_sub', '$roll_number');")
         or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
        if ($exam4!='');

        $sql6 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `school`.`academic` (`S_No`, `Exam`, `School`, `Year`, `Total_marks`, `Marks_obtained`, `Grade`, `Percentage`,`Major_subjects`, `Roll_no`) VALUES (NULL, '$exam4', '$hssc_school', '$hssc_year', '$hssc_total_marks','$hssc_marks', '$hssc_grade', '$hssc_percentage', '$hssc_sub', '$roll_number');")
         or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());


         if($sql1 && $sql2 && $sql3 && $sql4 && $sql5 && $sql6 ) 

                {
                    $myURL = 'success.php?sType=insert';
                    header('Location: '.$myURL);
                    exit;
                }

         else 
                 echo "Try again!";



 ?>
```

Initially i am checking only two fields, later i will check all the fields. Even if they are filled it give error. if i try this without checking empty field query it is working and saving information. Kindly guide me where i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note: Your `if ($examX!='');` clauses are useless. It will execute everything between `)` and `;` (which is nothing).

Comment: @GeraldSchneider should i remove ;  and write like if ($exam!=) ......

Comment: _You are handling POSTed values perfectly!_

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `if ($exam2!='')` `if ($exam3!='')` `if ($exam4!='')` conditions properly try to use them like that

```
       if (!empty($exam2)){
           $sql4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `school`.`academic` (`S_No`, `Exam`, `School`, `Year`, `Total_marks`, `Marks_obtained`, `Grade`, `Percentage`,`Major_subjects`, `Roll_no`) VALUES (NULL, '$exam2', '$ssc_ii_school', '$ssc_year_two', '$ssc_ii_total_marks','$ssc_ii_marks', '$ssc_ii_grade', '$ssc_ii_percentage', '$ssc_sub2', '$roll_number');")
         or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
         }
        if (!empty($exam3)){
            $sql5 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `school`.`academic` (`S_No`, `Exam`, `School`, `Year`, `Total_marks`, `Marks_obtained`, `Grade`, `Percentage`,`Major_subjects`, `Roll_no`) VALUES (NULL, '$exam3', '$o_level_school', '$o_level', '$o_level_total_marks','$o_level_marks', '$o_level_grade', '$o_level_percentage', '$o_level_sub', '$roll_number');")
         or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
         }
        if (if (!empty($exam4)){
            $sql6 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `school`.`academic` (`S_No`, `Exam`, `School`, `Year`, `Total_marks`, `Marks_obtained`, `Grade`, `Percentage`,`Major_subjects`, `Roll_no`) VALUES (NULL, '$exam4', '$hssc_school', '$hssc_year', '$hssc_total_marks','$hssc_marks', '$hssc_grade', '$hssc_percentage', '$hssc_sub', '$roll_number');")
         or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your database field Null then try.. it may be work